# Class of an object doesn't change the first time, after that it does

Tags: javascript, html, css

Now, the title might seem a little vague, because my question is a bit hard to describe in one sentence. I'll try to explain it as good as possible.

My website has a fixed header, and in that are 4 buttons. I made a little javascript file that changes the class of each button whenever you click it (If you click a button, the class changes to "menuButtonSelected" and all the other classes change to "menuButton"). Here's my javascript file:

```
function setButtonOne() {
    if(document.getElementById("buttonOne").className == "menuButton") {
        document.getElementById("buttonOne").className = "menuButtonSelected";
        document.getElementById("buttonTwo").className = "menuButton";
        document.getElementById("buttonThree").className = "menuButton";
        document.getElementById("buttonFour").className = "menuButton";
    }

    else if(document.getElementById("buttonOne").className == "menuButtonSelected") {
        // Do nothing
    }
}

function setButtonTwo() {
    if(document.getElementById("buttonTwo").className == "menuButton") {
        document.getElementById("buttonTwo").className = "menuButtonSelected";
        document.getElementById("buttonOne").className = "menuButton";
        document.getElementById("buttonThree").className = "menuButton";
        document.getElementById("buttonFour").className = "menuButton";
    }

    else if(document.getElementById("buttonTwo").className == "menuButtonSelected") {
        // Do nothing
    }
}

function setButtonThree() {
    if(document.getElementById("buttonThree").className == "menuButton") {
        document.getElementById("buttonThree").className = "menuButtonSelected";
        document.getElementById("buttonTwo").className = "menuButton";
        document.getElementById("buttonOne").className = "menuButton";
        document.getElementById("buttonFour").className = "menuButton";
    }

    else if(document.getElementById("buttonThree").className == "menuButtonSelected") {
        // Do nothing
    }
}

function setButtonFour() {
    if(document.getElementById("buttonFour").className == "menuButton") {
        document.getElementById("buttonFour").className = "menuButtonSelected";
        document.getElementById("buttonTwo").className = "menuButton";
        document.getElementById("buttonThree").className = "menuButton";
        document.getElementById("buttonOne").className = "menuButton";
    }

    else if(document.getElementById("buttonFour").className == "menuButtonSelected") {
        // Do nothing
    }
}
```

So each button has a seperate id (buttonOne, buttonTwo, buttonThree, buttonFour). In my html file, I set the `onclick` according to the button's id. So `buttonOne` would have an `onclick` of `setButtonOne()` and so on.

Here's the relevant part of my html code (excuse me for the formatting, somehow it copied that way...):

```
            <a href="http://www.ysbakker.eu/site/index.html#home"><div id="buttonOne" class="menuButtonSelected" onclick="setButtonOne();titleHome();">
                <p class="menuText">Home</p>
            </div></a>

            <a href="http://www.ysbakker.eu/site/index.html#projects"><div id="buttonTwo" class="menuButton" onclick="setButtonTwo();titleProjects();">
                <p class="menuText">Projecten</p>
            </div></a>

            <div id="buttonThree" class="menuButton" onclick="setButtonThree();">

            </div>

            <div id="buttonFour" class="menuButton" onclick="setButtonFour();">

            </div>
```

**So here's where the problem is.**

Whenever I reconsult my website, and I click on the second button, it doesn't change. When I click again, it does. Somehow, it will function normally if I click the third or fourth button. It's just whenever I click the second button, the `menuButtonSelected` class returns to the first one instead.

The only possibility to me would be that there's something wrong in the `setButtonTwo()` function, but I couldn't find anything.

Anyone knows how to fix this?

Note: If you want to see the website in function, the link's right [here](http://www.ysbakker.eu) (it's in dutch, but you'll get the concept)

Comment: Are you accidentally calling `setButtonOne` in your `onclick` event handler for button two? Also, the link you provided seems to work for me.

Comment: Please, show the HTML file as well. Are you setting the classes in the HTML as well?

Comment: Note that for the code to work, all menus buttons must be marked with `class="menuButton"`.

Comment: @EduardoFernandes That's already the case, just added the HTML so you can take a look at it

Comment: The code should work. What does `titleProjects();` do? Does it change the style? Have you tried removing it?

Comment: @EduardoFernandes The only thing it does is changing the title of the page, it does not affect the style at all. I'll try removing it now

Comment: Does your page submit everytime you clock the hyperlink?

Comment: @EduardoFernandes Well the links refer to an object's id, so I guess it does, yeah.

Comment: The submission is causing the problem. I will post the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I found a solution myself: it's as simple as redirecting to the full URL path with my redirection page.
Instead of redirecting to `[domain]/site` I redirected to `[domain]/site/index.html`. It's no longer giving me any trouble.

Comment: Bur this has nothing to do with the problem you posted

Comment: So you should not post it as an answer

Comment: I am just trying to help you here. A moderator may penalize you

Answer (score 2):

You need to return false in every javascript function so page does not submit.

Here is the HTML

```
<a href="http://www.ysbakker.eu/site/index.html#home"><div id="buttonOne" class="menuButtonSelected" onclick="return setButtonOne();">
    <p class="menuText">Home</p>
</div></a>

<a href="http://www.ysbakker.eu/site/index.html#projects"><div id="buttonTwo" class="menuButton" onclick="return setButtonTwo();titleProjects();">
    <p class="menuText">Projecten</p>
</div></a>

<div id="buttonThree" class="menuButton" onclick="setButtonThree();">

</div>

<div id="buttonFour" class="menuButton" onclick="setButtonFour();">

</div>
```

Here is the javascript:

```
function setButtonOne() {
    if(document.getElementById("buttonOne").className == "menuButton") {
        document.getElementById("buttonOne").className = "menuButtonSelected";
        document.getElementById("buttonTwo").className = "menuButton";
        document.getElementById("buttonThree").className = "menuButton";
        document.getElementById("buttonFour").className = "menuButton";
    }

    else if(document.getElementById("buttonOne").className == "menuButtonSelected") {
        // Do nothing
    }

    return false;
}

function setButtonTwo() {
    if(document.getElementById("buttonTwo").className == "menuButton") {
        document.getElementById("buttonTwo").className = "menuButtonSelected";
        document.getElementById("buttonOne").className = "menuButton";
        document.getElementById("buttonThree").className = "menuButton";
        document.getElementById("buttonFour").className = "menuButton";
    }

    else if(document.getElementById("buttonTwo").className == "menuButtonSelected") {
        // Do nothing
    }
    return false;
}

function setButtonThree() {
    if(document.getElementById("buttonThree").className == "menuButton") {
        document.getElementById("buttonThree").className = "menuButtonSelected";
        document.getElementById("buttonTwo").className = "menuButton";
        document.getElementById("buttonOne").className = "menuButton";
        document.getElementById("buttonFour").className = "menuButton";
    }

    else if(document.getElementById("buttonThree").className == "menuButtonSelected") {
        // Do nothing
    }
    return false;
}

function setButtonFour() {
    if(document.getElementById("buttonFour").className == "menuButton") {
        document.getElementById("buttonFour").className = "menuButtonSelected";
        document.getElementById("buttonTwo").className = "menuButton";
        document.getElementById("buttonThree").className = "menuButton";
        document.getElementById("buttonOne").className = "menuButton";
    }

    else if(document.getElementById("buttonFour").className == "menuButtonSelected") {
        // Do nothing
    }
    return false;
}
```

Note that each javascript false is returned and the onclick in each button returns the value of the function.

Here is the [link for the JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9TT2j/).

Comment: I did exactly what you suggested, but still it's not working. (Check the link, the blue line at the bottom still stays at the first button when you click the second one the first time.)

Comment: Have you tried the JSfiddle code I provided in the answer? If you test it, it works fine. I am saying that because then you should compare that code with yours :).

Comment: You mentioned that the code is not work properly, but if you pay attention, it actually is fine.

Comment: the code you supplied is indeed working just fine, but the thing is, I tried what you suggested and my code now is exactly like yours, though I still have the same problem. I also tried loading my page in another web browser, but the same problem occurs.

Comment: Have you tried check the values in the classes, either using cosole.log or alert?

Comment: Nevermind, it looks like the old version was still in my browser cache. Works fine for me now.

Comment: Nope, showing problems again. After some troubleshooting I found another solution.

Comment: Which solution? It would be nice to have it posted

Comment: I just posted my solution. Thanks for your help though.

Comment: Ir is not fair to downvote my answer since it works and solves the problem

Comment: I have not downvoted your answer, I just unaccepted it, because it didn't work for me...

Comment: I just unaccepted it so it shows as minus reputation, in fact it just removes the reputation you got when I accepted your answer